# user is not allowed to do action [find] on [test.postmessages]

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mern

I'm getting this error
**{"message":"user is not allowed to do action [find] on [test.postmessages]"}**

This is my code

```
import PostMessage from "../models/postMessage.js";

export const getPosts = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const postMessages = await PostMessage.find();

        res.status(200).json(postMessages);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the content of the file postMessage.js?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works fine on local mongodb. I guess you are using Atlas. If so, do the follwoing steps:

Go to:

```
Database Access > Edit (user) > Built-in Role > Change the role to atlasAdmin > update user
```

I hope this solves your problem.